# What does "global quotient" mean?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, terminology

[This article](http://math.colorado.edu/~casa/seminars/WAGS/WAGSposters/geraschenko.pdf) asks the question: "Is every variety with quotient singularities a global quotient of a smooth variety by a finite group?"

> **Question.** What branch of math does the concept of a global quotient belong to, and what does this phrase mean?

Comment: Global quotient just means quotient, as in the title. The term global is being used to contrast with being locally such a quotient, which I believe is what "quotient singularities" means.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "global" here is pleonastic: "global quotient" just means "quotient".  In other words, the question is whether there exists a smooth variety $U$ and a finite group $G$ acting on $U$ such that your variety is the quotient of this action.  The point of the word "global" is that the hypothesis of "quotient singularities" is exactly that this condition holds locally: every point in your variety has a neighborhood which is such a quotient (I think "neighborhood" means in the etale topology in this context but I might be wrong).  So the question is whether you can go from knowing that your variety locally looks like such a quotient to knowing that it really is such a quotient ("globally").